# Android Studio & Java build issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to finish off the first tutorial in the Android Studio documentation, but I can't even seem to do that.

I keep getting a:

> Error:(17, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MESSAGE

Here is the code to my `DisplayMessageActivity.java` file:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
    layout.addView(textView);

  }
}
```

The tutorial I am trying to follow is here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Do you have the `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ...` line in `MainActivity`, as shown in bold in the example code?

Comment: post your mainactivity code

Answer (score 1):

There is no static variable with name EXTRA_MESSAGE. Add `public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = <Some Message String>`. And this error will be resolved

Comment: Well thank you so much guys. Yes, it was exactly that simple. I missed that obvious line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no static variable with name EXTRA_MESSAGE. Add public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = .